# Meteor changing package name with colon to suit Windows

Tags: meteor

I used to develop meteor app using Mac. I have written package for app with name `foo:bar` and package is under `packages/foo:bar`

This week meteor team has officially released metero.js for Windows. Cloning the the git repo to windows is failing because of colon `:` in the directory name.

Is there any official way to migrate/rename package directory name in Mac so that it works properly across all operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name the package folder anything you want. In the `package.js` file under the `Package.describe` method, use `foo:bar` as the name instead.

Meteor will use this as the name of the package instead of the name of the directory containing the package thereon.